# How to read only the beginning of the last line?

Tags: c++, class, file-read

I want to make a program that creates a class array of N objects, where N is a number of the last object read from my CSV file.

My CSV file is separated like this:

`serial_number;name;surname;gender;phone_number;e-mail`

I used `seekg` to go to the end of the last line, but I can't figure out how to ignore the first 4 delimiters when reading backwards and only read the serial number.

Comment: It might be easier to just read through the file once, ignoring all the lines of data in it until you get to the last line, parse that last line in the usual way, allocate your array of N objects, then `seek()` back to the beginning of the file and do it again.  Trying to parse a CSV file backwards would be tricky.

Comment: Reading backwards through files like this is for the birds. You have to seek back one character at a time, then `peek` the current character and see if it's what you're looking for (delimiters or newline, whichever works for you). Much better to read line by line, and discard the last line after reading a new line. The last line standing will be the last line in the file.

Comment: Just read the whole thing and parse it. C++ can do this quickly enough the overhead is trivial for all but the largest of files. Monkeying around with file descriptors and making all these OS calls will be way slower than just reading the whole thing in and parsing it one-shot.

Comment: Are you creating an object for each line in the file? If so, you have the wrong approach.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am, I thought it may be the best way to save that data so I can practice working on it. What's the good approach?

Comment: why not just push into a stack and after reading everything just pop the serial number ?

Comment: @ARealNewbie you should create the objects as you read each line from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a program that creates a class array of N objects, where N is a number of the last object read from my csv file.

If you are creating an object for each line in the file, you should just read each line, one at a time. Then create the object for that line and add it to a list. You don't need to determine the number of objects. Instead, you create objects until you reach the end of the file.

If you insist on parsing data from the last line, the best way is still to read the entire file one line at a time. Throw away all but the last line and parse it for the data you want. Don't try to go backwards from the end of the file.